# Network module - integration with WordPress/Drupal

Tags: wordpress, drupal, vis.js

has anyone used a CMS (WP/Drupal) to manage vis.js network data?

I would need a simple network (nodes with images and URLs) and CMS taxonomy would probably be a good source of data, but I don't know where to start from.

Any advice or examples would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Suggest go for WordPress with this plugin https://github.com/Ugotsta/visjs-timelines-for-wordpress.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I am looking for a way to integrate the **network** vis.js module, not timeline.

Of course, I searched thoroughly for a plugin before asking here :)